# Android View setVisibilty(View.Gone) is not working on Lollipop

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, visibility

I have a hearder_view which is header of a main list view. My header_view, contains another list view and textview(s) in it.

When user taps on header_view, I am setting the visibility of header_view's listview to GONE or VISIBLE.

It works fine on Android versions earlier to lollipop, but on lollipop, GONE works but it sends the its list view content to background of main list view and when I tap anywhere on screen, only then its completely gone.

I tested on Nexus 5 and Xperia Z3 (both on lollipop) both got same issue, tested on other non-Lollipop devices it works fine on them.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please draft a simple test code sample

Comment: @Kaibuki Put the whole listview inside a linear layout and setVisibilty(View.Gone) for the linear layout.

Comment: @David, Yes I have done that too, the whole listview is inside the linear layout.